# Pizza Ordering Program Not Working

Tags: python

Theres something wrong with my code:

```
REG_PIZZA = ["Meatlovers", "Hot 'n' Spicy", "BBQ Chicken and Bacon", "Satay Chicken", "Super Supreme", "Seafood Deluxe"]
GOURM_PIZZA = ["Hawaiian", "Veg Deluxe", "Beef and Onion", "Ham and Cheese", "Pepperoni", "Cheese Supreme"]
numPizza = 0
selection = 0
totalCost = 0
deliverCost = 3

    def orderPizza():

        global numPizza
        global selection 
        global order
        global totalCost   

    pizzaOrder = 0
    order = []

    if pizzaOrder < numPizza:

        print(" ") 
        print(" ")
        print(" ")
        print("=======Regular Pizza's=======")
        print("Press 1 for " + REG_PIZZA[0] + " - $8.50")
        print("Press 2 for " + REG_PIZZA[1] + " - $8.50")
        print("Press 3 for " + REG_PIZZA[2] + " - $8.50")
        print("Press 4 for " + REG_PIZZA[3] + " - $8.50")
        print("Press 5 for " + REG_PIZZA[4] + " - $8.50")
        print("Press 6 for " + REG_PIZZA[5] + " - $8.50")
        print("=======Gourmet Pizza's=======")
        print("Press 7 for " + GOURM_PIZZA[0] + " - $5.00")
        print("Press 8 for " + GOURM_PIZZA[1] + " - $5.00")
        print("Press 9 for " + GOURM_PIZZA[2] + " - $5.00")
        print("Press 10 for " + GOURM_PIZZA[3] + " - $5.00")
        print("Press 11 for " + GOURM_PIZZA[4] + " - $5.00")
        print("Press 12 for " + GOURM_PIZZA[5] + " - $5.00")
        print("==========Exit Menu==========")
        print("Press 0 to Exit")
        print("=============================")        
        selection = raw_input("Enter your choice (0-12):  ")

        if selection == 0:
            sys.exit()
        elif selection == 1:
            print(REG_PIZZA[0], "- $8.50")
            order.append(REG_PIZZA[0])
            print(order)
            pizzaOrder = pizzaOrder + 1
            totalCost = totalCost + 8.50
            print(" ")
            print(" ")
            print(" ")
        elif selection == 2:
            print(REG_PIZZA[1], "- $8.50")
            order.append(REG_PIZZA[1])
            print(order)
            pizzaOrder = pizzaOrder + 1
            totalCost = totalCost + 8.50
            print(" ")
            print(" ")
            print(" ")
        elif selection == 3:
            print(REG_PIZZA[2], "- $8.50")
            order.append(REG_PIZZA[2])
            print(order)
            pizzaOrder = pizzaOrder + 1
            totalCost = totalCost + 8.50
            print(" ")
            print(" ")
            print(" ")
        elif selection == 4:
            print(REG_PIZZA[3], "- $8.50")
            order.append(REG_PIZZA[3])
            print(order)
            pizzaOrder = pizzaOrder + 1
            totalCost = totalCost + 8.50
            print(" ")
            print(" ")
            print(" ")  
        elif selection == 5:
            print(REG_PIZZA[4], "- $8.50")
            order.append(REG_PIZZA[4])
            print(order)
            pizzaOrder = pizzaOrder + 1
            totalCost = totalCost + 8.50
            print(" ")
            print(" ")
            print(" ")
        elif selection == 6:
            print(REG_PIZZA[5], "- $8.50")
            order.append(REG_PIZZA[5])
            print(order)
            pizzaOrder = pizzaOrder + 1
            totalCost = totalCost + 8.50
            print(" ")
            print(" ")
            print(" ")
        elif selection == 7:
            print(GOURM_PIZZA[0], "- $5.00")
            order.append(GOURM_PIZZA[0])
            print(order)
            pizzaOrder = pizzaOrder + 1
        totalCost = totalCost + 5.00
        print(" ")
        print(" ")
        print(" ")
    elif selection == 8:
        print(GOURM_PIZZA[1], "- $5.00")
        order.append(GOURM_PIZZA[1])
        print(order)
        pizzaOrder = pizzaOrder + 1
        totalCost = totalCost + 5.00
        print(" ")
        print(" ")
        print(" ")
    elif selection == 9:
        print(GOURM_PIZZA[2], "- $5.00")
        order.append(GOURM_PIZZA[2])
        print(order)
        pizzaOrder = pizzaOrder + 1
        totalCost = totalCost + 5.00
        print(" ")
        print(" ")
        print(" ")
    elif selection == 10:
        print(GOURM_PIZZA[3], "- $5.00")
        order.append(GOURM_PIZZA[3])
        print(order)
        pizzaOrder = pizzaOrder + 1
        totalCost = totalCost + 5.00
        print(" ")
        print(" ")
        print(" ")
    elif selection == 11:
        print(GOURM_PIZZA[4], "- $5.00")
        order.append(GOURM_PIZZA[4])
        print(order)
        pizzaOrder = pizzaOrder + 1
        totalCost = totalCost + 5.00
        print(" ")
        print(" ")
        print(" ")
    elif selection == 12:   
        print(GOURM_PIZZA[5], "- $5.00")
        order.append(GOURM_PIZZA[5])
        print(order)
        pizzaOrder = pizzaOrder + 1
        totalCost = totalCost + 5.00
        print(" ")
        print(" ")
        print(" ")
    elif pizzaOrder == numPizza and numPizza == 1:
        print("==Order Details==")
        print(order)
        print("Total Cost:", totalCost)
        print("==Thank You", customerName + "==")

    elif pizzaOrder == numPizza and numPizza == 2:
        print("==Order Details==")
        print(order[0])
        print(order[1])
        print("Total Cost:", totalCost)
        print("==Thank You", customerName + "==") 

    elif pizzaOrder == numPizza and numPizza == 3:
        print("==Order Details==")
        print(order[0])
        print(order[1])
        print(order[2])
        print("Total Cost:", totalCost)
        print("==Thank You", customerName + "==")

    elif pizzaOrder == numPizza and numPizza == 4:
        print("==Order Details==")
        print(order[0])
        print(order[1])
        print(order[2])
        print(order[3])
        print("Total Cost:", totalCost)
        print("==Thank You", customerName + "==")

    elif pizzaOrder == numPizza and numPizza == 5:
        print("==Order Details==")
        print(order[0])
        print(order[1])
        print(order[2])
        print(order[3])
        print(order[4])
        print("Total Cost:", totalCost)
        print("==Thank You", customerName + "==")




def deliveryPickup():

    option = int(input("Delivery or Pickup? (1 - Delivery OR 2 - Pickup):   "))

    if option < 1 or option > 2:       
        print("That is not a valid input - Try Again")

    global numPizza  
    global totalCost

    if option == 1:

        totalCost = totalCost + 3
        customerAddress = raw_input("Enter your Address: ")
        customerPhone = raw_input("Enter your phone number: ")
        print("Thank you", customerName, "Your Address is", customerAddress, "and your phone    number is", customerPhone)
        print(" ")
        numPizza = raw_input("Enter number of Pizza's Wanted (Max 5):  ")
        print(" ")
        print(" ")
        print(" ")
        print(" ")
        orderPizza()

    if option == 2:
        numPizza = raw_input("Enter number of Pizza's Wanted (Max 5):  ")
        print(" ")
        print(" ")
        print(" ")
        print(" ")
        orderPizza()


customerName = raw_input("Enter your name please: ")

deliveryPickup()
```

This is what i type in:

```
Enter your name please: Chris
Delivery or Pickup? (1 - Delivery OR 2 - Pickup):   2
Enter number of Pizza's Wanted (Max 5):  2


=======Regular Pizza's=======
Press 1 for Meatlovers - $8.50
Press 2 for Hot 'n' Spicy - $8.50
Press 3 for BBQ Chicken and Bacon - $8.50
Press 4 for Satay Chicken - $8.50
Press 5 for Super Supreme - $8.50
Press 6 for Seafood Deluxe - $8.50
=======Gourmet Pizza's=======
Press 7 for Hawaiian - $5.00
Press 8 for Veg Deluxe - $5.00
Press 9 for Beef and Onion - $5.00
Press 10 for Ham and Cheese - $5.00
Press 11 for Pepperoni - $5.00
Press 12 for Cheese Supreme - $5.00
==========Exit Menu==========
Press 0 to Exit
=============================
Enter your choice (0-12):  1    # <-- I select meatlovers
# then nothing happens....
```

What is wrong?
I cant seem to figure it out, i've re written the menu ordering 3 times. 
It cuts out when you make your choice for selecting the pizza

Comment: Just a grammatical point which will help with the syntax highlighting, it's just Pizzas, not Pizza's

Comment: This is *a lot* of code to ask somebody to debug for you. In the future, please try to reproduce your problem within a minimal part of code that still demonstrates the issue. See http://sscce.org

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast your `selection` as an `int`. It should then work:

`selection = int(raw_input("Enter your choice (0-12):  "))`

instead of:

`selection = raw_input("Enter your choice (0-12):  ")`

or for greater flexibility:

```
try:
    selection = int(raw_input("Enter your choice (0-12):  "))
except ValueError:
    selection = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast  selection to an int

```
selection = int(raw_input("Enter your choice (0-12):  "))
```

It would probably be a good idea to use a while loop and a try/except to check that the data entered is correct for all your inputs, if you cast selection to an int and someone enters a string, your program will crash.